# Assign a boolean value inside and "if" statement in Java?

Tags: java

In Java, I was looking at this code and noticed that the `boolean` value is assigned the value of true inside the `if` statement. I thought that an `if` statement would evaluate a statement and not allow the programmer to set a value. What is the purpose of this? `"Take out for dinner"` will never be reached, correct?

```
public class Dinner {
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
     boolean isKeeperFish = false;
     if (isKeeperFish = true) {
       System.out.println("Fish for dinner");
     } else {
       System.out.println("Take out for dinner");
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: That is correct.  What is the problem you have with the code?

Comment: @CrApHeR I'm just curious why this would have an "else" statement?

Comment: It is not necessary and some compilers will show a warning at compile time telling you that the `else` never will be reached.  It depends of each compiler.

Comment: comparing a boolean variable to a boolean literal `b == true`causes a thousand kitten videos to be removed from the internet never to be seen again every time you do it! and leads to extremely subtle bugs such as this one as well. `b != false` gets a fatwa issued against you and all the kitten videos in the future never happen!

Comment: Yes, in your example it's dead code and I do get a warning in eclipse that the variable is never used (because the variable isn't used) `true` is a constant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You test for equality using double equals signs:

```
if(isKeeperFish == true) {
}
```

You can use assignment inside if-clauses for something like this:

```
int a = 7;
int b;
if((b = a + 5) == 12) {
    System.out.println(b); // Will print 12;
}
```

Though it's usually discouraged since it looks a bit messy and the assignment is easy to miss.