# How do booleans work in if statements in Java?

Tags: java, for-loop, boolean

I'm trying to understand the basics of `for` loops and how they work with `boolean`s. There is a simple few lines of code that I wrote and I don't quite understand why the output is what it is.

```
public class notes { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean[] test = {false, false, true};
        if (test[0] = false) {
           System.out.println("yes");
        } else {
           System.out.println("no");
        }
    }
}
```

I would assume that because the boolean value at index 0 in the test array is false, then this if statement should also print yes. However, it prints no. Why is this?

Comment: You're using an assignment operator, instead of checking it with ==.

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30180184/assign-a-boolean-value-inside-and-if-statement-in-java

Comment: test[0] = false is not a comparison

Comment: Note, by Java naming conventions, classes should begin with uppercase.

Comment: Also wondering where the `for loop` part of the question is?..

Comment: Edit: My mistake for writing for loops, I meant to ask how booleans work with if statements. Thank you for the help everyone!

Answer (score 3):

Try it like this.  Since conditionals result in a true or false condition you can just use the boolean by itself.  Since you want it to print yes when false, you need to make it true so the conditional will succeed.  So invert the condition by prefixing a bang `!` (aka the NOT operator).

```
public class notes {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       boolean[] test = {false, false, true};
    
       // if false do it.
       if(!test[0]) {
         System.out.println("yes");  
       } else {
          System.out.println("no");
       }
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using an assignment operator `=`, instead of using a comparison operator `==`, hence you *don't compare*, but rather assign a `false` value to the index 0 of your array and the same `false` is then evaluated as a boolean value; therefore, `else` block executes.

Try this instead:

```
public class notes { 

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean[] test = {false, false, true};

        if(test[0] == false) { //you had a mistake here.
           System.out.println("yes");
        } else {
           System.out.println("no");
        }
    }
}
```

Note, that you can alternatively negate boolean expression with `!` unary operator, like `!booleanValue`. In your case it would look like `!test[0]`.

[Have](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/opsummary.html) a look at operators in Java.

Comment: Best practices are to not test `booleans` with `==`.  EIther use them by themselves or invert the condition.  The `bytecode` is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

You are assigning `false` to the first element of the array, which evaluates to `false` and causes the `else` branch to be executed instead. You need to use `==` for comparison and in the case of `boolean`s, you can simply use the logical not operator (`!`) to check if it is `false`. It is always redundant to compare boolean values, as the result of comparison is a boolean.

```
if(!test[0]) {
  System.out.println("yes"); 
} else {
  System.out.println("no");
}
```